# Grading a probability model

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following challenge,  and I want to ask if there is a common approach to such problems :

I want to create a probability model for an experiment, let's say the experiment is rolling a dice. But the probability for each of the sides of the dice to win, changes from each experiment (based on various variables) - my challenge is to describe in the best way, what is the probability of each result to occur, for each experiment.
Moreover, There are not endless amount of experiments to be performed. 
"My machine" is a probability model to predict the outcome of a football match, It can always be one of the three : 1 - home team wins, x - draw, 2 - away team wins. The input can be everything that might change the outcome of the game.. From game to game to probabilities for each result should change, and there are only a few hundreds games a year, What is the best way to rate my algorithm? is that by grouping between games that received the very same probabilities for each result and tell how many of them were accurate?

What is the method to rate my machine? assuming that there is no option to run an endless number of the very same experiment.. the next experiment will be slightly different so my machine might give another probability for each of the possible events...

I hope I was clear,
Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: This is not clear.  How does the machine "say" what the probability is?  From your dice example, it would appear that all you can observe is the outcome.  If you throw a $7$ that doesn't tell you the probability of throwing a $7$ and it obviously doesn't tell you the probability of throwing a $6$.  I think you should add more detail.  Exactly what is it you can observe?  Exactly what is known a priori about the way the probabilities shift over time?  Use a concrete example.  If your problem makes sense for coin tosses, I suggest working with that for clarity (only two outcomes).

Comment: Thanks, 
"My machine" is a probability model to predict the outcome of a football match, It can always be one of the three : 1 - home team wins, x - draw, 2 - away team wins.
The input can be everything that might change the outcome of the game..
From game to game to probabilities for each result should change, and there are only a few hundreds games a year,

What is the best way to rate my algorithm? is that by grouping between games that received the very same probabilities for each result and tell how many of them were accurate?

Comment: Ok, so rewrite your post explaining that and phrasing your question in that precise setting.  As it stands, it is not at all clear what you are asking.